# How do I reference the value of a different attribute in a Rails ActiveRecord Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model, Lease, with attributes ends_on (date), and notice_days (integer) I would like to write a query that returns all records that have an ends_on date that is less than today's date plus notice_days for that record.
In straight SQL (for my Postgresql db) the query is:

```sql
SELECT * FROM leases WHERE ends_on < CURRENT_DATE + notice_days
```

I can easily write a query to compare against today's date + some fixed buffer

```rb
Lease.where(ends_on: ...Date.current + 30).all
```

But I don't want the fixed buffer, I want a buffer (notice_days) that is unique to each record.

I do realize that I could execute the sql shown above using exec_sql, but I would like to learn how to do this with a straightforward ActiveRecord query.

**Edit**

Stefanyuk's answer below does in fact answer my question, but I am looking for a way to write the ActiveRecord query with key value pairs as arguments to the where method in the hopes of making the query less database dependent. It seems that this should be possible but I have tried many ways of passing the attribute name without success.

This does not work, but I am looking for something similar that does:

```rb
Lease.where(ends_on: ...(Date.current + :notice_days))
```

Is there a way to replace the symbol :notice_days in that example with a reference to the attribute notice_days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using `interval`

```sql
SELECT * FROM leases WHERE ends_on < CURRENT_DATE + interval '1 day' * notice_days
```

Or with `Rails`

```rb
Lease.where("ends_on < CURRENT_DATE + interval '1 day' * notice_days")
```

Or with `Arel`

```rb
Lease.where(Lease.arel_table[:ends_on].lt(Arel.sql("CURRENT_DATE + notice_days")))
```

Comment: Your answer works - thank you! I was looking for a slightly different approach but I did not ask my question properly to get the answer I was looking for. While interval does not appreciably differ from my sql approach above, enclosing the entire query in quotes does answer my question.

Comment: Is it possible to accomplish the same query with arguments in the where clause rather than a quoted string? It seems this would make the query less database dependent

Comment: It's also possible to do this with `Arel`, but in this case you also have to have some enclosing  query in quotes `arel_table = Lease.arel_table
    Lease.where(arel_table[: ends_on].lt(Arel.sql("CURRENT_DATE + notice_days")))`